# how to disable parent window on open child in Qt?

Tags: qt

I want to forbid any action in the main window, including its closure. while open child

I try:

```
// child window
Settings::Settings(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Settings)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ((QWidget*)parent)->setEnabled(false); // or parent->setEnabled(false);
 ...
```

makes segmentation fault on `Settings->show();`

and I try send signal from Settings constructor/destructor
to `MainClass` slot

```
void MainClass::Enable(bool enable)
{
  qDebug() << "detect signal enable"; // 
  this->setEnable(enable);
}
```

but signal wasn't sent.

ofcourse i connect `Settings` to `MainClass`)).
signal emiting works in any other function of `Settings`.

Comment: “I want to forbid any action in the main window, including its closure“ - usually one would make Settings a (modal) QDialog for this. But if parent is pointing to a valid object, I don't see how this would crash. (Run it in a debugger)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For child windows it would be better to inherit from [`QDialog`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#details) (**not** [`QWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#details)) because the first one is designed specially for dialogs. From Qt docs:

> The `QDialog` class is the base class of dialog windows.

The method you need is [`QDialog::exec()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec). It opens your dialog as a [modal window](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#modal-dialogs) which will block the input for other application windows until it is closed.

Comment: @JohnDoe how do we access parent class widget from QDialog modal window?